# OCR with python and tesseract

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, tesseract

### Sample code for OCr

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesser import *

image_file = 'E:\Downloads\menu.jpg'
im = Image.open(image_file)
text = image_to_string(im)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file, graceful_errors=True)
print ("=====output=======\n")
print (text)
```

### Error

```
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesser\__init__.py", line 64
    except errors.Tesser_General_Exception, value:
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

.[I was following this tutorial on python and OCR using tesseract](http://www.manejandodatos.es/2014/11/ocr-python-easy/)

And I am using python 3 and I had downloaded the tesseract library and added to anaconda libraries.But upon first running it I had received error showing print missing parenthesis so I changed that and now I find this error anyone can help me with this it would be great.
Am also adding the tesseract wrapper's source code here
"""OCR in Python using the Tesseract engine from Google

```
http://code.google.com/p/pytesser/
by Michael J.T. O'Kelly
V 0.0.1, 3/10/07"""

PIL import Image
import subprocess

import util
import errors

tesseract_exe_name = 'C:\Users\SACHIN\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pytesser\\tesseract' # Name of executable to be called at command line
scratch_image_name = "temp.bmp" # This file must be .bmp or other Tesseract-compatible format
scratch_text_name_root = "temp" # Leave out the .txt extension
cleanup_scratch_flag = True  # Temporary files cleaned up after OCR operation

def call_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename):
    """Calls external tesseract.exe on input file (restrictions on types),
    outputting output_filename+'txt'"""
    args = [tesseract_exe_name, input_filename, output_filename]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
    retcode = proc.wait()
    if retcode!=0:
        errors.check_for_errors()

def image_to_string(im, cleanup = cleanup_scratch_flag):
    """Converts im to file, applies tesseract, and fetches resulting text.
    If cleanup=True, delete scratch files after operation."""
    try:
        util.image_to_scratch(im, scratch_image_name)
        call_tesseract(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)
        text = util.retrieve_text(scratch_text_name_root)
    finally:
        if cleanup:
            util.perform_cleanup(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)
    return text

def image_file_to_string(filename, cleanup = cleanup_scratch_flag, graceful_errors=True):
    """Applies tesseract to filename; or, if image is incompatible and graceful_errors=True,
    converts to compatible format and then applies tesseract.  Fetches resulting text.
    If cleanup=True, delete scratch files after operation."""
    try:
        try:
            call_tesseract(filename, scratch_text_name_root)
            text = util.retrieve_text(scratch_text_name_root)
        except errors.Tesser_General_Exception:
            if graceful_errors:
                im = Image.open(filename)
                text = image_to_string(im, cleanup)
            else:
                raise
    finally:
        if cleanup:
            util.perform_cleanup(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)
    return text


if __name__=='__main__':
    im = Image.open('phototest.tif')
    text = image_to_string(im)
    print (text)
    try:
        text = image_file_to_string('fnord.tif', graceful_errors=False)
    except errors.Tesser_General_Exception, value:
        print "fnord.tif is incompatible filetype.  Try graceful_errors=True"
        print value
    text = image_file_to_string('fnord.tif', graceful_errors=True)
    print ("fnord.tif contents:", text)
    text = image_file_to_string('fonts_test.png', graceful_errors=True)
    print (text)
```

Comment: @user10089632 and second ?.I did as exactly shown in tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
except errors.Tesser_General_Exception, value:
```

Replace it for

```
except errors.Tesser_General_Exception as value:
```

It works for me. It is all about the upgrade from `Python2` to `Python3`.

Comment: bro this issue was I was using python2 lib in python 3 and nomatter what there would be some piece of code that would have issue and I actually had to debug the entire library .Even after that some issues persisted so i decided to use python2.7 and everrything fell into its place